# Windows 7 advanced file searching criteria syntax

Tags: search, windows-7

I need some help with the windows file search syntax for the criteria that the file name ends with 'xml' and the contents of the file contain the string 'bean'. So far I have it as:

```
System.FileName:~>"xml" AND
```

what do I need to put after the `AND`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
filename:~> xml AND content: bean
```

Comment: `filename: *.xml AND content: bean` is how I would go about doing it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Out of curiosity, what if I wanted to add to that criteria the fact that I want the search limited to only two particular subfolders of the folder on which I am performing the search? Say explorer is open at the parent of the 2 subfolders and I want to type in the criteria?

Comment: You might need a batch file to do that.